# Input text for username and password is not showing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been building login form and everything went great, until i opened up Firefox and try it on. The text you input is not even showing like in Chrome and IE.

Anyway here is the CSS i've been using for login:

```
#login-wrapper{
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#378f90
}

#login-wrapper .item-list,#login-wrapper h2,#login-wrapper label{
    display:none
}

#login-wrapper #edit-actions,#login-wrapper .form-actions,#login-wrapper .form-item{
    margin:0
}

#login-wrapper input,#login-wrapper input:focus,#login-wrapper textarea,#login-wrapper textarea:focus{
    margin:1.25rem 0;
    padding:1.875rem 0 2.5rem;
    line-height:1.75rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:none;
    resize:none
}

#login-wrapper textarea,#login-wrapper textarea:focus{
    padding-bottom:1.25rem;
    padding-top:.9375rem
}

#login-wrapper input.placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus.placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea.placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus.placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper textarea{
    overflow:hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word
}

#login-wrapper input[type=submit]{
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:1.25rem 0;
    padding:0 0 0 1.25rem;
    width:4.375rem;
    height:4.375rem;
    line-height:1.5625rem;
    font-size:1rem;
    font-weight:500;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-image:url(../images/icon-login-big.jpg);
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius:.1875rem;
    -moz-border-radius:.1875rem;
    border-radius:.1875rem
}
```

Comment: You have quite a few rules using `-webkit` and `-ms` prefixes, but Firefox is neither of those.

Comment: Can you try [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)ing it to show a minimal version reproducing the problem? It will be a lot easier to spot the error.

Comment: I am guessing your input background color is white and your text color is also white, please try changing the text color to `color:#000000;`

Comment: Strange..you have text `placeholder` and background `input[type=submit]` both in white color

Comment: @LuthandoLoot the background color is not white, so you would see the color. OP: You set your wrapper to `display: none`. How are you showing your inputs?

Comment: Please provide the HTML required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue only because of `#login-wrapper` to `display: none`

I have updated code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljcp8fse/)

```css
#login-wrapper{
/*    display:none;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#378f90
}

#login-wrapper .item-list,#login-wrapper h2,#login-wrapper label{
    display:none
}

#login-wrapper #edit-actions,#login-wrapper .form-actions,#login-wrapper .form-item{
    margin:0
}

#login-wrapper input,#login-wrapper input:focus,#login-wrapper textarea,#login-wrapper textarea:focus{
    margin:1.25rem 0;
    padding:1.875rem 0 2.5rem;
    line-height:1.75rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:none;
    resize:none
}

#login-wrapper textarea,#login-wrapper textarea:focus{
    padding-bottom:1.25rem;
    padding-top:.9375rem
}

#login-wrapper input.placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus.placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea.placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus.placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea::-moz-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,#login-wrapper textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:#fff
}

#login-wrapper textarea{
    overflow:hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word
}

#login-wrapper input[type=submit]{
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:1.25rem 0;
    padding:0 0 0 1.25rem;
    width:4.375rem;
    height:4.375rem;
    line-height:1.5625rem;
    font-size:1rem;
    font-weight:500;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-image:url(../images/icon-login-big.jpg);
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius:.1875rem;
    -moz-border-radius:.1875rem;
    border-radius:.1875rem
}
```

```html
<div id="login-wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea>test area</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change

from:
padding:1.875rem 0 2.5rem;

to:
padding:1.875rem 1 2.5rem;

Thank you for support :)